# Get the path of inheritance from virtual base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual

I have the following code snippet, and I want to know that which path do c++ compiler choses to inherit the member.

```
class B
{
    public:
    void display()
    {
        cout << "B";
    }
};

class B1 : virtual public B
{
};

class B2 : virtual public B
{
};

class C : public B1, public B2
{
};

int main()
{
    C c;
    c.display();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Is it really possible to have the path chosen by the compiler and if there is then please tell. Might be a basic question but please take some time for it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See "diamond problem"

Comment: What do you mean "which path"? `B` is inherited once, so all paths are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not chosen by the compiler, it's defined by the language. `B` is virtual, so `C` has exactly one `B` base class. Its base classes will be constructed in the order `B`, `B1`, `B2`.

Comment: So, do you mean that B's members are inherited only through B, not from B1 or B2. B1 or B2 will inherit their own members only to C ? Also, do inheriting like `Class C : public B2, public B1` will construct in this order `B, B2, B1` ?

Comment: Both B1 and B2 instances have a B base instance and can access its members - but its the same instance. That's what virtual does. And yes, the declared order affects the order of construction. You might find this easier if you try it yourself (write to `cout` in each constructor, say) or get yourself a good book on C++.